# Is there a Google cloud synthetic monitoring solution

Tags: google-cloud-platform, stackdriver

Does GCP provide any synthetic monitoring solution similar to https://www.appdynamics.com/product/synthetic-monitoring/ ?

Answer (score 0):

Rather off-topic for SO. But just in case your post is not getting deleted...

There are several more or less similar products in the [Cloud Management Tools](https://cloud.google.com/products/management/) category, most notably [Stackdriver Monitoring](https://cloud.google.com/monitoring/).

Answer (score 0):

[Uptime checks](https://cloud.google.com/monitoring/uptime-checks/) is the one you need.

PS: it is [free](https://cloud.google.com/stackdriver/pricing)

> Uptime checks, including uptime checks metric data, advanced alerting, and notifications are non-chargeable and available to everyone.